# Windows Compact Embedded 2013 Custom SDK Compile Error

Tags: windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded-standard

I'm attempting to build a custom SDK in VS 2013 for my Windows Compact Embedded 2013 OS. I've been able to successfully build the OS and deploy to a VM using Hyper V, so I know it's ok.

However, when I try to build an SDK (so I can do some .Net development, if there's any other way to do that please let me know), it fails on compile with the following:

> C:\WINCE800\build.log(34) : Message: - Processing Project Template folder - C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\vstemplates\visualbasic\Windows Embedded Compact\DotNetCompactSDK\1033\emptyproject
>
> C:\WINCE800\build.log(35) : Message: - Processing Project Template folder - C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\vcprojects\Windows Embedded Compact\DotNetCompactSDK
>
> C:\WINCE800\build.log(36) : Error: adding required files {log="C:\WINCE800\build.log(36)"}
>
> Error: GenSdk build error: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. {log="C:\WINCE800\build.log(37)"}

The build.log doesn't provide any additional information other than what I've posted.
I've only found this issue twice in my Google searches so I guess it's rare. Any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

There is a bug in the SDK build tools. It will be fixed in the next release

Find a work-around here:

http://guruce.com/blogpost/wec2013-gensdk-build-error